# C++ OpenCV get Bounding Box From Vector Of Points

Tags: c++, opencv

I have vector of points i drawed by my self :

```
std::vector<CvPoint> shape1 = paintshape(0);
```

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/brkfri6uv/box.jpg]

Now i need to get a bounding box object (points) around this shape ,

i have searched the web for answeres but every topic is talking about 
recognizing the edge of some object inside whol image file and then making the bounding box.

in my case its different ,

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

get the [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) for your points:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

// please use stuff from the cv:: namespace, not the outdated Cv*
std::vector<cv::Point> shape1 = paintshape(0); 
cv::Rect r = cv::boundingRect(shape1);
```

Comment: berak,Thanks you very much . regretfully i get this error :      1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Rect_<int> __cdecl cv::boundingRect(class cv::_InputArray const &)"

Comment: please check, what paintshape(0) returns. also, see, if you're linking release libs to a debug build or the other way.

Comment: the return of paintshape is correct because i am able to paint the shape after the return and also when debuging i see the vector of points with values inside |:

Comment: I found the fix ^^ , the libs i used wasent with the debug "d" letter at the end .